# how to scale my image - responsive design

Tags: css

I can't manage to make the image (logo) on my website (www.seandorsman.nl) scaleable.
I'm using the following CSS:

```
.logo
{       
height: auto;
width: 100%;
max-width: 920px;
background-color:#0FF;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

And the following HTML:

```
<div class = "logo" >
<img src = "images/logo.png"/>
</div>
```

I have been looking on the web and all I can find is that i need to use

```
width:100%;
height:auto;
max-width:920px;
```

What am I doing wrong, why doesn't the image scale?

PS. You can also check my website for the full code.

Comment: why don't you set those propeties on image element, but on the <div> instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong way around (well, I guess it doesn't matter but I would do it this way). Try:

```
width:920px;
height:auto;
max-width:100%;
display: block; /*for IE*/
```

**This needs to be on the image itself, not the wrapper for the image**

Comment: allright, i'll try that. But what properties do i give to the wrapper then?

Comment: whatever's left from the ones you take out and add to the image I guess. the wrapper will be full width anyway without specifying 100%

Comment: Awesome, i got it working!
although i had to put this in the .logo:
  
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
 max-width: 920px;

Comment: you have some odd styling on your body and .container on your website...why not set margin on body to 0 and not use negative margins on container?

Comment: great, don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you. Welcome to SO btw

Comment: for some reason if i do that i will still have an edge on top of the page.

Comment: even with body {margin: 0;padding: 0;} ??

Comment: yup, i've uploaded it to my site so you should be albe to see it there.

Comment: no, you've used `.body` rather than `body` `.` means a class, you don't need it for an element selector. Try removing the .

Comment: oh god. It works like a charm! Thanks mate!
btw. is there any way i could ask you some more quick questions if you don't mind?

Comment: great. why don't you start a new question and add the link here if you have other questions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612500/scaling-the-navigation-bar-responsive-design

there you go! I'd appreciate your help!