# scaling the navigation bar - responsive design

Tags: css

I'm trying to make my website fully responsive, and I'm stumbling upon the navigation bar; I cannot seem to make it responsive. My coding is as following:

```
<div class = "navbar" >
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Collectie</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Zomercollectie</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Wintercollectie</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Kerstcollectie</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Over ons</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>   
</div>
```

And the CSS as following:

```
.navbar
{   
height: 50px;
width: 920px;
max-width:100%;
background-color:#2d2d2d;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

/* NAVBAR CSS */

nav ul ul 
{
display: none;

}

nav ul li:hover > ul 
{
display: block;
}
nav ul {
background:#2d2d2d; 
color:ffffff;
font-size:30px;
padding: 0 20px;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
margin-top: 0;

}

nav ul:after 
{
content: "";
clear: both; 
display: block;
}

nav ul li 
{
float: left;
}

nav ul li:hover 
{
background: #4b545f;
}

nav ul li:hover a 
{
color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a {
display: block; 
padding: 7px 93px;
color: #757575;     
text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul ul 
{
background: #5f6975; 
padding: 0;
position: absolute; 
top: 100%;
}

nav ul ul li 
{
float: none; 
border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
position: relative;
}
nav ul ul li a 
{
padding: 15px 40px;
color: #fff;
}   

nav ul ul li a:hover 
{
background: #4b545f;
}

/* END of NAVBAR CSS */
```

I would like to make it scale the whole thing, including fonts when they are too big, and without the buttons stacking vertically.

Any idea?

Comment: I've never heard of inline-table before? display table would do what you want but it won't work in older browsers. Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries for the font resizing issues

Comment: You have height: 50px; and width: 920px; These are fixed values. If you want to make your site "responsive" then you need to make these relative values, ie. relative to the width and height of their container.

Comment: Thanks, I will read further into this soon. I'm going to bed now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, i've fixed it. It was in the height element. I shouldn't have used them at all.